# Separate array items based on type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to *split* an array in two, based on the two possible types of the items.
I tried a first generic approach like this

```js
function partitionErrors<T, E extends Error>(arr: (T | E)[], predicate: (elem: T | E) => elem is E): [T[], E[]]  {
  return arr.reduce<[T[], E[]]>((memo, res) => {
    if (predicate(res)) memo[1].push(res)
    else memo[0].push(res)
    return memo
  }, [[], []])
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, new Error('boom')]

// errros is Error[] but num is (number | Error)[] ❌
const [num, errors] = partitionErrors(arr, (i): i is Error => i instanceof Error)
```

but TypeScript doesn't detect `num` as a number.

I then use a more direct function:

```js
function p2<T>(arr: (T | Error)[]): [T[], Error[]]{
  return arr.reduce<[T[], Error[]]>((memo, res) => {
    if (res instanceof Error) memo[1].push(res)
    else memo[0].push(res)
    return memo
  }, [[], []])
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, new Error('boom')]

// num2 is number[] ✅
const [num2, errors2] = p2(arr)
```

and this time, everything works out great!

Why does the use of a type predicate in the parameter affect the type inference of the output?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYCdawQUXeudAZwB4AVAGkR0QFMAPKWsAEyOv0ID4AKDdAFyIeZRAB9qASgDaAXSrJ0tFjAiomQnrQA2tALZDREnJMQBeLnV17EMdiaHSycqjjmzEiAN4AoT0qgQdCR+ADolFhAIWhInF2p3Xh49fTgqJSJTC28-T1tgYUVlVXVaHgzJUxS9OGkARllQ5BAiAAty2kzczx0iWkRq2oAGRua2jq68xACgpEHcgF8qaXj3SR8Fnx9QSGwkZAAmcl5+TSMOAnQZWUlHZ3kLwndff1pA4MQwiKiYuIe8S6JHjJVLpTpZSwvPIwAoTWxgIhQVCQWhwAoAwhVVL1UYtdoVbpWPoDbEjJp4ibrKYzD7zTxLRArB5rDZbCAIRGffDmRl1KgHKgAZioYFoAHdHugeAByABGcDgemlklkWwA9Gq6PgCOw7JK5IhZSAoIgwCAbHqeGa9LLaOhxJLrohADLkPnZCJN0mtVDtlyIHjMKAwWHgYAxxD4+CoPBgt1stnsnHt2Rg8MRyOiaMd6s11oOCdN5tt6ANgFByN0cz15n1JogHAMoA6Rq5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, type `T` is inferred from type of your array `arr`. So `T` will be `number | Error`. This is why you get `nums` is of type `number | Error`.

Now, why the second function works? Because we filter out ALL elements of type error, while in the second case this is not guaranteed. The predicate function is expected to return `true` if the input is of type `E`. But what if the input extends both types, i.e `E` and `T`? We are not sure what the function `predicate` will return in this case. Maybe the predicate function is as follows:

```js
function predicate(elem: any): boolean {
  if(elem instanceof Number) return false;
  else if(elem instanceof Error) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

If we pass an object that extends both `Number` and `Error` to this function it will return `false`. That is why you get both types.

To solve your problem you can explicitly mention that type `T` is not of type `Error`. To do this you declare a type `NotError`

```js
type NotError<T> = Exclude<T, Error>;

function partitionErrors<T, E extends Error>(arr: (NotError<T> | E)[], predicate: (elem: T | E) => elem is E): [T[], E[]]  {
  return arr.reduce<[T[], E[]]>((memo, res) => {
    if (predicate(res)) memo[1].push(res)
    else memo[0].push(res)
    return memo
  }, [[], []])
}
```

Comment: Woah, thank you! Now I understand it and the `Exclude<T, Error>` fixes it, it's awesome!